# Select2 Remote search: Preloaded Default dropdown options not showing with select2 remote search

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have been trying to show the default dropdown list of options while implementing the Select2 remote search. I have gone through various implementations online but so far have been unable to achieve that.

My HTML Code

```
<select id="search_states" style="width: 100%">
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
</select>
```

My JS Code

```
/*Search States */
  $("#search_states").select2({
      placeholder: 'Search state',
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      ajax: {
        url:"/search-states",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        theme: "bootstrap",
        processResults: function (data) {
          return {
            results:  $.map(data, function (item) {
                  return {
                      text: item.st_name,
                      id: item.state_id
                  }
              })
          };
        },
        cache: true
      }
  })
```

As mentioned earlier I have gone through the official documentation and various other sources online but can't figure out what's wrong I am doing.

[image]

The image above is what I am seeing when I click on the field. "Pennsylvania" should not be pre-selected instead it should show in a drop-down. Like in the image below.
The remote search is working perfectly fine. It's just default options not showing when the user clicks on the select2 field before typing the search term.
[image]

Can somebody please help me out here?

Comment: From looking at select2, you'll need to add your (2) "default" options programmatically - https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items - Now I don't know if these options will be removed from the entire list of "states", nor do I know if these (2) "default" options will be listed on top. With any plugin, you can't expect "exactly what you want". It's built to be used as the developer wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

could you use a default empty option?

```
<select id="search_states" style="width: 100%">
 <option></option>
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
</select>
```